# What parameters about galaxies can be measured using SAO DS9?

Tags: observational-astronomy, galaxy, radio-astronomy, software, ds9

I am trying to determine and plot various parameters for galaxies on SAO DS9. RA & dec, angular size to a fair extent, and contour plotting are a few of the aspects which I could determine using the same. What else can I determine (specifically for galaxies) using [DS9](https://sites.google.com/cfa.harvard.edu/saoimageds9)?

Also, are there any other softwares that can help me determine various parameters of galaxies?

Answer (score 1):

SAO DS9 is a powerful software tool for viewing and analyzing astronomical images, and there are many other parameters you can determine for galaxies using DS9. Here are some additional parameters you may be interested in:

Surface brightness: You can use DS9 to measure the surface brightness of a galaxy, which can provide information about its structure and composition.

Ellipticity: DS9 can help you determine the ellipticity of a galaxy, which can provide information about its shape and orientation.

Radial profile: You can use DS9 to create a radial profile of a galaxy, which shows how its brightness changes as a function of distance from the center. This can provide information about the galaxy's structure and composition.

Spectral properties: DS9 can also be used to analyze spectral data, which can provide information about a galaxy's composition and physical properties.

In addition to DS9, there are many other software tools available for analyzing astronomical data. Some popular options include IRAF, IDL, and Python-based tools like Astropy and PyRAF. These tools offer a wide range of capabilities for analyzing and visualizing astronomical data, so you may want to explore them to see which one best fits your needs.